# How to get CCSprite's size after changing scale

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This does not work:

```
CCSprite *testscale=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:starFrame];
        testscale.scale=0.5;
float starWidth=testscale.contentSizeInPixels.width;
        CCLOG(@"contentpixels: %f contentsize: %f",starWidth, testscale.contentSize.width);
```

The two  outputs in CCLOG both show the original pixel size of the sprite, not the size after scaling.

Is there a way to get it *without* doing this?...

`float displayWidth=starWidth*testscale.scale;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the boundingBox property of CCNode:

```
[testscale boundingBox].size.width
[testscale boundingBox].size.height
```

This should give you the width and height you want, taking into account any transformation (scaling, rotation) you have made to the sprite.