# Cocos2d Equivalent of Sprite Kit's size property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hey I learned sprite kit before i went to Cocos2d but one thing I miss about sprite kit is how you can change the size of the sprite just by using cgSizeMake(x,y); . I can't seem to find the equivalent of where to use cgsizemake. I tried with contentSize but it didn't change anything and made it just move. I know setScale can change the size but setScale bases it off the initial size of the image and you just name the length and the width with setScale.Is there a equivalent of this in Cocos2d-swift or am i stuck with setScale.

Comment: You should mention at the beginning that you're working with Swift. You haven't even tagged the language you're using.

Comment: i tagged objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getContentSize()` to get the original size of the sprite and use that to `setScale()` to the size you need.

Example:

Full size: 200x200px
Desired size: 20x20px
`sprite.setScale(20.0/sprite.getContentSize().width, 20.0/sprite.getContentSize().height);`

Edit: Also, you could subclass or create an extension to create a method called setSize() that does this.

Edit 2: To get the size of the sprite after scaling, see here: 
[How to get CCSprite's size after changing scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076306/how-to-get-ccsprites-size-after-changing-scale) 
Also added another link to related for scaling a sprite to an exact size.

Related:

- [COCOS2D-X: scale sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340428/cocos2d-x-scale-sprite)
- http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/setcontentsize-in-cc-sprite-doesnt-set-the-size-instead-only-changes-the-position-of-the-sprite/5506/3
- [Scale CCSprite to exact size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695540/scale-ccsprite-to-exact-size)

Comment: Well number set scale only takes a float and that is a problem. Number two i need to be able to compare two sizes of sprites and getcontentsize gives the original size of image

Comment: You see my original image is 198 and i need it to be 200 exact floats are too short here.

Comment: I updated my answer, see Edit2. Also, I added another link to a stackoverflow question which explains how to scale a sprite to an exact size.